# Getting callers IP

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have application based on [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

Method I use to test connection to server (in client app):

```
public class PBMBService : IService
{
    private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient();
        tbInfo.Text = service.Ping().Replace("\n", "\r\n");
        service.Close();
    }

//other methods
}
```

Service main function:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/PBMB");

        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PBMBService), baseAddress);

        try
        {
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IService),
                new WSHttpBinding(),
                "PBMBService");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Serwis gotowy.");
            Console.WriteLine("Naciśnij <ENTER> aby zamknąć serwis.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();


            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nastąpił wyjątek: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Ping() function decaration

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://PBMB")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Ping();
}
```

Ping() function implementation

```
public class PBMBService : IService
{
    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=PBMB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;

    private void Message(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " -> " + message);
    }

    public string Ping()
    {
        Message("Ping()");
        return "Metoda Ping() działa.";
    }
}
```

How can I put caller's IP in Message method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original blog is available through the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140206221353/http://keyvan.io/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5). Note that you'll need to be using WCF 3.5 or later per the author's post.

The code from the article is below;

Service Contract

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ClientInfoSample
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string value);
    }
}
```

Implementation with retrieving IP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ClientInfoSample
{

    public class MyService : IService
    {

        public string GetData(string value)
        {

            OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
            MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty = messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

           return string.Format("Hello {0}! Your IP address is {1} and your port is {2}", value, endpointProperty.Address, endpointProperty.Port);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: Can you give me an exaple how to use this?

Comment: so message method body would be Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " -> " + message + "from ip "+HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);

Comment: I can't refer to HttpContext in my method